# Compare two spreadsheets in a workbook, find the differences and record the differences on the first spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

**I need a way to compare two spreadsheets in a workbook, find the differences, then write those differences on the spreadsheet in sequential order in the same column below the existing numbers.**

Sheet1 has participating dealer numbers. All dealer numbers are listed in Column C beginning in cell 5. All dealers participating fill in downward. (note: these dealers are listed in a District Order so some of the cells will have the word TOTAL in it instead of a dealer number) Column B hosts the District Letter. I also need to carry over this letter as well.

**"Sheet1":**

```
A    207475   
A    207775  
B    TOTAL
```

In Sheet2 I have listed the complete list of Dealers to compare against.

**"Sheet2":**

```
A    206600   
A    207475  
B    206624
```

I would like for my missing dealers to show below a section I have set up as missing dealers like the below example: (ignoring the District Totals) (yet capturing the District letter in Column B as well)

**MISSING DLRS.**

```
A    207775   
A    206600  
B    206624
```

Comment: I am currently using:  =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet1!B1,'Accord 2DR 4C'!$C$8:$C$145,0)),Sheet1!B1,"")  Placed in a column at the far right of all my other data.  It brings results to the right and leaves spaces between the results.  I need something placed in the same column C without any spaces between the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those problems that should really be solved by using a database, since excel isn't terribly well suited for it. BUT, excel can do anything, so here's how I would solve it using nothing but cell formulas.

1. On your second sheet in a column (hidden if you prefer) BEFORE your column of dealers, add a countif formula to determine if the dealer is in Sheet1 or not. Here I have wrapped the countif in a IF formula, and if the countif returns a 0 (the dealer was not found), I have it spit out the ROW I am currently on... this will be important in the next step. Assuming your list of dealers on sheet2 is also in "C" starting at row 5 `IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C,sheet2!C5)=0, ROW(),"")`
2. In a column directly after that last one we just created we are going to use the RANK formula to number the dealer rows from 1 to whatever where the dealer was not matched on Sheet1 (this is why we needed the ROW()). `=RANK(A5,$A$5:$A$500,1)` (here I assumed that Step 1 column was 'A'
3. Now we have all the dealers that are missing ranked from top to bottom with consecutive numbers. In a new sheet, or wherever you want your list of Dealers not found in Sheet1, make a column and number the rows 1 through however many missing dealers there could be. I will assume Sheet3, Column A, starting at Row 1
4. In the next column over do a vlookup function to search for the first missing dealer with `=Vlookup(A1,Sheet2$A$5:$A$500,3, false)` and copy that function down all the rows.

It's a little complicated, and an unorthodox use of both ROW() and RANK(), but it keeps you out of a databases, VBA, or worse yet... manual.